# How can I troubleshoot an Oracle DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB problem?

Tags: oracle

I am trying to execute an external command procedure from Oracle. What I have so far is;

Oracle Procedure;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DO_HOST_COMMAND 
(
  HOST_COMMAND IN VARCHAR2 
, ARGUMENT_LIST IN VARCHAR2 
, ARGUMENT_COUNT IN NUMBER 
, DELIMITER IN VARCHAR2 
) AS 
  JOB_ID VARCHAR2(100) := 'myjob_'||TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISSFF6');
  CURRENT_ARGUMENT_COUNT NUMBER;
  CURRENT_ARGUMENT VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN

  DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (JOB_NAME    => JOB_ID,
                              JOB_TYPE    => 'executable',
                              JOB_ACTION  => 'c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe',
                              NUMBER_OF_ARGUMENTS => ARGUMENT_COUNT + 1,
                              AUTO_DROP   => TRUE);
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_JOB_ARGUMENT_VALUE (JOB_ID, 1, HOST_COMMAND);
  FOR CURRENT_ARGUMENT_COUNT IN 1..ARGUMENT_COUNT
  LOOP
    CURRENT_ARGUMENT := GET_DELIMITED_ELEMENT(ARGUMENT_LIST,DELIMITER,CURRENT_ARGUMENT_COUNT);
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_JOB_ARGUMENT_VALUE (JOB_ID, CURRENT_ARGUMENT_COUNT + 1, CURRENT_ARGUMENT);
  END LOOP;
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.RUN_JOB (JOB_ID);

END DO_HOST_COMMAND;
```

Windows command procedure;

```
c:
cd \Temp
echo in test.cmd > test.log
copy %1  %2
```

SQL command to run this;

```
exec do_host_command('c:\temp\test.cmd','test1.txt|test2.txt',2,'|');
```

The result is;

```
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

However nothing occurs. When I run;

```
select * from user_scheduler_job_run_details where trunc(log_date) = trunc(sysdate);
```

It says the job succeeded. I looked in the alert log and the traces files and can find nothing. I have changed the permissions of the c:\temp folder to everyone full access.

Not sure where to look to find the problem. What additional troubleshooting should I do?

EDIT:

This is running in Oracle 12c R2 on Windows 2016.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're not calling `cmd.exe` correctly.  You need to pass a `/C` switch to `cmd.exe` before the name of the script.  In other words, you need to get the database to run the command

```
cmd.exe /C C:\temp\test.cmd test1.txt test2.txt
```

not

```
cmd.exe C:\temp\test.cmd test1.txt test2.txt
```

The body of your stored procedure should be changed to this:

```
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (JOB_NAME    => JOB_ID,
                              JOB_TYPE    => 'executable',
                              JOB_ACTION  => 'c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe',
                              NUMBER_OF_ARGUMENTS => ARGUMENT_COUNT + 2,  -- up to + 2 here
                              AUTO_DROP   => TRUE);
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_JOB_ARGUMENT_VALUE (JOB_ID, 1, '/C');                -- extra arg
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_JOB_ARGUMENT_VALUE (JOB_ID, 2, HOST_COMMAND);        -- now arg 2
  FOR CURRENT_ARGUMENT_COUNT IN 1..ARGUMENT_COUNT
  LOOP
    CURRENT_ARGUMENT := GET_DELIMITED_ELEMENT(ARGUMENT_LIST,DELIMITER,CURRENT_ARGUMENT_COUNT);
    -- Change from + 1 to + 2 in the line below:
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_JOB_ARGUMENT_VALUE (JOB_ID, CURRENT_ARGUMENT_COUNT + 2, CURRENT_ARGUMENT);
  END LOOP;
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.RUN_JOB (JOB_ID);
```

I made this change to your stored procedure and it worked, in that I got the database to run your script.

Comment: Luke I gave you credit as you got the right answer. However I had intuited this from a number of other posts I found, none of which specifically stated I needed the /c or /q. I was actually about to answer my own question.